# Error: cannot open display: :0 for Selenium tests

Tags: selenium, jenkins

Firstly I was getting the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
```

So I have used `export DISPLAY=:0` to circumvent this problem. Followed to that I have found Selenium tests were running using the root user and all was fine.

However now I can see when these tests are getting executed from Jenkins the following error is coming up:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
No protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

I am running this on a Redhat 6 box.

Comment: Can you add some more information please, what OS? is it on a machine and account with access to an X session?

Answer (score 3):

You can download the [Jenkins xvnc plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvnc+Plugin) and make that plugin start(and export) a virtual display for selenium to use.
The jenkins user may not have access to the :0 display.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to solve this problem is making changes to the jenkins start script.

The solution that works on Ubuntu for me correctly is as follows:

1.Open Jenkins shell script located at: /etc/init.d/jenkins.

2.Add the following lines as follows before PATH variable:

```
/usr/bin/X :0 vt7 -ac
export DISPLAY=:0
xhost +
```

Comment: `sudo service jenkins restart` now gives me the following errors: `(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) Server is already active for display 0
        If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
        and start again.
(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
(EE)
No protocol specified
xhost:  unable to open display ":0"`

Comment: There might be an error in your Xorg configuration. A solution is detailed here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/69896/cant-run-x-configure-server-is-already-active-error.  However, I would suggest you use the plugin as suggested by Amey.

Comment: @sjmach, I've my jenkins server installed on Windows machine. In that case what is equivalent of this. I mean which file I need to update with the changes you've suggested.

Comment: @TDHM: Are you using a Windows machine locally or on a cloud provider (VM)?

Comment: For our project, it is on VM but I also have prepared Jenkins master on my machine locally. First one is more important. If you've solution for second one, please do suggest that as well.

Comment: @TDHM: Assuming it is on Azure, this might work for you - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-portal. The idea is to do a remote desktop connection to run the tests.

Comment: @sjmach thanks but unfortunately the VM is in-house. Is there any other way to configure it?

Comment: Even if the Vm is in house you can use rdp. How do you connect that machine?