# Jenkins - Selenium WebDriver Firefox error - Failed to connect

Tags: linux, firefox, selenium, ant, jenkins

I have Jenkins on a CentOS machine.

I installed all required plugins, configured my Jenkins project.

**Jenkins runs the tests with firefox on the local machine(Selenium 2.44/Firefox 31) . 
No RC control or XVFB plugins.**

The X server is started and DISPLAY is set to 0.0

- The source code, come from a SVN repository
- I use ANT for the build

**Everything worked fine, the tests run properly with Jenkins**. And now, from one day to the next, all tests fail for no reasons. I changed nothing in the configurations.

```
[mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myTestProject/workspace/report
[mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myTestProject/workspace/report/xml
[junit] Running test.TestConnection
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 46,24 sec
[junit] Error: 
[junit] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
[junit] Error: no display specified
[junit] Error: no display specified
[junit] 
[junit]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
[junit]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
[junit]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
[junit]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
[junit]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
[junit]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
[junit]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
[junit]     at tools.WebDriverInitHelper.initDriver(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at tools.TestBase.before(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[junit]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[junit]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[junit]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[junit]     at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
[junit]     at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
[junit]     at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
[junit]     at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
[junit]     at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
[junit]     at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
[junit]     at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
[junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
[junit]     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
[junit]     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
[junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
[junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
[junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
[junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
[junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
[junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
[junit]     at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:38)
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:532)
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1179)
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:1030)
```

I don't understand what happened. Firefox has not updated.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: See this thread

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653127/selenium-error-no-display-specified>

Comment: Thanks but the fact is I want launch test on the Jenkins machine and not with Xvfb plugins or RC.

Comment: What is the value of the environment variable `$DISPLAY` ? try to output it in your build to validate it is set to 0.0, and check that X server is running under the same display number. In your Jenkins's job config you can set env var if needed

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : [Error: cannot open display: :0 for Selenium tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773363/error-cannot-open-display-0-for-selenium-tests)

1.Open Jenkins shell script located at: /etc/init.d/jenkins.

2.Add the following lines as follows before PATH variable:

- /usr/bin/X :0 vt7 -ac
- export DISPLAY=:0
- xhost +