# jenkins cannot run firefox: No protocol specified Error: cannot open display: :0

Tags: linux, firefox, jenkins, python-3.4

I have installed jenkins as a service on linux mint. I am trying to run tests written in python and script cannot run firefox. This line is a problem.

...
self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
...

When i log in as jenkins user, i can't run firefox. getting this error :

> (process:3758): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion
>   'sys_page_size == 0' failed No protocol specified No protocol
>   specified Error: cannot open display: :0

Firefox works when i run it from my (logged in) user.

Comment: there is a screen in the machine that runs jenkins?

Comment: No, i started jenkins as a service : service jenkins start

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: cannot open display: :0 for Selenium tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773363/error-cannot-open-display-0-for-selenium-tests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install a virtual framebuffer in your machine and it will work.
Now i'm using Xvfb, but there are many others.
Here is some tutorials to setup your machine:

- http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/
- http://www.labelmedia.co.uk/blog/setting-up-selenium-server-on-a-headless-jenkins-ci-build-machine.html

Also, there is this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin

Comment: I resolved this with using selenium grit. Thank you all.